# Which infinity do integrals diverge to?

Tags: integration, infinity

When we say $\int{f}dx = \infty$, what is the cardinality of that $\infty$?

Comment: Depends on how the integral is defined. Is it a standard Riemann integral of a real function?

Comment: This actually means the integral value is not bounded.

Comment: @Marc "Depends on how the integral is defined" Well, actually... no.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up two notions of "infinity". One concerns the sizes of sets. A set is infinite (in that sense) when there's a one to one correspondence with a proper subset. That's the infinity that you mean when you talk about cardinality.

The other "infinity", written $\infty$, is sometimes confusing shorthand used when discussing limits. To say that a limit "is infinite" means that the quantity is eventually larger than any number specified in advance. $\infty$ is not a number of any kind.

Your confusion is quite common, and unsurprising. It's too bad we chose to use one word two different ways.

Comment: Hmm. Is there a natural way to extend this $\infty$ to a number? Or maybe I want to ask, why would it be disingenuous to say its $\omega$?

Comment: There is no good way to make the $\infty$ limit a number. $\omega$ is a standard symbol for yet a third kind of "infinity". It's the first infinite _ordinal number_. Identifying it with the $\infty$ in limits would be worse than disingenuous, it would be very confusing.

Comment: Could you give an intuition as to why there is no good way to make it a number?

Comment: If it's to be a "number" it will have to satisfy the usual rules for addition. Then from $\infty + 1 = \infty$ you could conclude that $1=0$. There is no good (natural) way to bend the rules of arithmetic that would allow $\infty$ to be a number without leading to a contradiction. You can define good arithmetic rules for the cardinal (counting) and ordinal (ordering) infinities. But they are not the usual rules for numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic

Comment: Right, so that goes back to my original question. Why, intuitively, would it be wrong to use, say, ordinal arithmetic for this $\infty$?

Comment: Because it's another kind of thing with its own context and rules. You probably want $\infty + 1 = \infty$ but in ordinal arithmetic $\omega + 1 \ne \omega$. Don't try to squeeze square pegs into round holes.

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming there's no practical reason to even try extending $\infty$ to $\omega$ (even if we don't care if $\infty + 1 > \infty$). Thanks.